# Sql Server - Data warehouse design - Unique identifier for a customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, data-warehouse

I have a data warehouse that was designed by someone else. That person states that having a unique identifier for each customer that doesn't change with time is impossible. Not knowing data architecture very well I want to know if that is true.

If possible, how complex would it be? Given that any other information about the customer might change at some point.

Thanks

Comment: How are we to know whether your customer identifier will change over time?

Comment: Well, it's true, think about it: First name, last name, middle initial, etc. these are all non-unique. How many people named John H. Smith do you think exist? One? Next, SSN. Some people don't have them, some people don't know them, some people won't provide them, and they can get re-used. E-mail address, phone number, address, etc. can all change. So rather than try to disprove, why don't you tell us what unique identifier for a customer you think *could* be used and would never change?

Comment: Sql Server has a way to have a GUID as an identifier which is just for this purpose. It doesn't change over time. It's an identifier. Any other attributes can change as needed. Things like name, email address, etc are attributes. Auto-incrementing PK ID would do the same job, but doesn't scale as well over distributed systems.

Comment: @Nikki9696 I think they meant a *natural* unique identifier (but am quite happy to be wrong).

Comment: A natural one? No, there is nothing like that, as far as I can imagine. Anything can change. People get married, change names, email, address, etc. That's why we have GUIDs and ID fields.  =)

Comment: @Nikki9696 yes, I know that, and you know that, but I'm not clear the OP and/or his co-worker knows that.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, this answers my questions. I'm going to read more about GUIDs and the see if it can be implemented.

Sorry for creating the confusion about whether this had to be a natural key or not, as it doesn't. Should have been more clear there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data warehouse information usually comes from some other system. That system should have been designed to have a surrogate key if people could not be uniquely identified. It is very rare for people to have a good unique identifier that is not a surrogate.  Emails are inappropriate as they change (and people may have multiple emails) and can be reused for other people, SSNs are not as unique as you might expect, even things like medical liscence numbers for doctors end up not being unique due to data entry errors in source systems. Names are clearly not unique not even when combined with other information such as address. I have never seen, in the hundreds of databases that I have had reason to query, any one which had a good unique identifier for a person that was not a surrogate key.

If the designers of the orginal system were incompetent (no database table ever should be missing a primary key) then the data warehouse indeed may not have a way to uniquely identify individuals and the chances of there being duplicates in the data are right at 100%. There is no point in adding a surrogate key to a data warehouse if it didn't come from the originating system. How would you know if this John Smith was id 1234 or id 4567 when updating the information?